# Transmit string output of a linux command to a php server

Tags: linux, terminal, command, raspberry-pi3, temperature

So there is this linux command

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

that displays the temperature of the CPU in the terminal.
And I have a cronjob, that calls a bash script that opens a php file on a remote server with wget

```
wget http://example.com/checkin.php -qO -
```

Is there any way to include the CPU temperature in the link my bash script contains so I can save it in a MySQL database? 
For example:

```
wget http://example.com/checkin.php?cpu_temp=48.4
```

Or is there any other simple way to monitor and log CPU temperature on a remote raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$()` to subsitute the output of a command into the command line:

```
wget http://example.com/checkin.php?cpu_temp=$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Where can I learn more about these kind of linux terminal tricks? What are they called?

Comment: It's not a "trick", it's one of the most basic operations in shell scripting, analogous to calling functions in traditional programming languages. It should be explained in any book or tutorial on writing shell scripts. And of course it's in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)

Comment: It's called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution)